# Communication in a simple GUI (C++ / SDL2)

Tags: c++, gui, sdl2

I've spent a few months now working on a fairly simply 2D game engine with SDL and C++. I'm now trying to develop a simple but well-featured GUI suitable for most games.

Right now I'm really struggling on figuring out how I should handle communication between the GUI and the other parts of the game / engine that might want to use it.

For example, the "shop" game state may have a list of items that I want to display on a shop GUI, along with their prices and quantities, i.e "Wooden sword / 30GP / 5". Obviously I need to get this information to the GUI in order for it to be useful, along with a way of notifying the shop component which item has been clicked/given focus. Seeing as the internal representation of an object such as an "item" or an "inventory" can vary wildly, how do I get the data I want to/from the GUI in a way that doesn't require excessive coupling between the two components?

I'd really appreciate anyone's advice on how to approach this issue, and I fully appreciate that my understanding is flawed.

Finally, I'm set on developing it from the ground up as a learning exercise, so I'm not really interested in GUI libs for SDL (it seems none of them are updated for SDL2 anyway).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to know how GUI libraries work. In fact, you could even have a look on some of them to see how they get these things done (for example, you may have a look at GTK+ docs, or Qt docs to see the interface)

However, assuming that you're not building the whole GUI library, but rather some basic `Window`/`Text`/`Image`/`TextLabel`/`Checkbox`/`RadioButton`/`Button` library, I am going to share **one** possible approach how to do it.

---

### Intro - rendering & data storage

Let's say you have a `Window` class. It already handles some basic functionality, like rendering and moving. The class also takes care of *adding widgets*. Widgets are `Text` or `Image`, for example.

```
class Window
{
    ...
    void render() const;    
    void move(const Vector & offset);
    void addWidget(const Widget newWidget); // Or you could use a reference, it depends on where do you want to store them/if you want to manipulate with them during their lifetime
    ...
}
```

Of course, you could be adding widgets to some grid cells, or you could give some offset relative to window on top of that.

`Widget` class could look like this:

```
class Widget
{
    ...
    virtual void render() const = 0;
    ...
}
```

I think it's clear for you now how you populate the window with the necessary information. `Widget` - derived classed will contain them. For example:

```
class Text: public Widget
{
    Text(const std::string);
    ~Text();

    void render() const
    ...    
}

// Somewhere else in your code
for (const int &obj : weapons)
    windowListingAllTheWeapons.addWidget(Text(obj.getName()));
```

The widgets will be displayed by calling their `render()` methods in the `render()` method of the window, which stores all the widgets (or references/pointers to them).

### Handling events

Now all you have to do is to add some `handleEvents()` method to `Window`, which will call `handleEvents()` of its respective widgets. This may get complicated, but as long as you stay in one-layer-depth, it's easy-peasy.

`handleEvents()` will take care of catching events which occurred in the area of the widget and `Widget` will invoke `onEvent()` methods (for example `onClick()`, `onHover()`, `onMouseRelease()`, etc), which will be appropriately overrided in the derived classes.

```
Widget::handleEvents(Event & event) // I don't know exactly how SDL handles events. I assume here that all the mouse events caught in Window class get distributed based on their position
{
    // this is kind-of-a-pseudo-code. I don't know SDL
    if(event.type == Event::Type::MouseClick)
    {
        onMouseClick(Mouse::getPosition());
    }
    // Yeah, it's better to use switch for multiple options
}

Button::onMouseClick(const Vector & position)
{
    this.setClicked()
    this.invokeSomeOtherAction()
}
```

---

### Disclaimer

This is not a tutorial on creating a GUI library. It's how I make GUI for small, not-GUI-heavy games. This is an overview of the process of creating **quick'n'dirty** GUI system. Anyone reading this, who is more interested in the topic should have a look at **Observer** pattern, **Qt's Signal And Slot**, **MVC** and should spend some time researching even more approaches on how to implement GUI.

Comment: Alright - this seems to be pretty foolish after reading it. Let me know if it's too stupid, so I can remove it :D

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is actually exactly what I needed for my purposes. I was overthinking the design and not paying attention to the fundamentals. Thanks again!